# ColdFusion 10 and Azure

Tags: coldfusion, azure-sql-database

I'd like to play around with SQL Azure.

Do you think ColdFusion 10 supports SQL Azure seamlessly?  I'm not talking about edge cases, but I did see something about how [CF9 would not return the Recordcount property if there were no rows](http://house-of-fusion.10909.n7.nabble.com/SQL-Azure-and-Coldfusion-9-td71573.html), along with a comment that CF9 didn't support Azure officially.

And [this site](http://www.brianloesgen.com/blog/2012/7/5/connecting-cold-fusion-10-to-azure-sql-database.html) says "We tested this using with ColdFusion 10 installed in an Azure Virtual Machine", which is not what I want because then I'd have to buy another license of CF10.

What I'd like to do is connect to SQL Azure from my HostMySite VPS that is already running CF10.

Answer (score 1):

That seems very bad making SQL calls over the internet.  I would recommend strongly against this.

Either install SQL on your VPS or ColdFusion on your Azure machine.